# Как организовать обмен сообщениями между страницей и расширением chrome?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chrome-extension

Всем привет!

Впервые пишу вопрос и расширение для Гугл хрома и мне нужно связать свой сайт с этим расширением с помощью сообщений.

Манифест имеет поля:

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [
      "http://localhost:3000/*",
      "http://localhost:6006/*"
    ],
    "run_at": "document_end",
    "all_frames": false,
    "js": ["content.js"]
  }],
 "permissions": [
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "notifications",
    "nativeMessaging",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "http://localhost:3000/*",
    "http://localhost:6006/*"
  ],

  "externally_connectable": {
    "matches": [
      "http://localhost:3000/*",
      "https://localhost:3000/*",
      "http://localhost:6006/*"
    ]
  },
```

Документация хрома говорит о том, что для того, чтобы отправить сообщение, нужно использовать метод
`chrome.runtime.sendMessage`, с указанием ID расширения из его настроек в браузере, который я добавил на страницу сайта.

Для получения такого сообщения нужно выдать разрешения, которые, прописаны в манифесте в **permissions**

Получать сообщения я пробовал с помощью методов:
 `chrome.tabs.onMessage.addListener, chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` и  `chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener` который вообще не доступен в content.js файле.

При попытке оправки сообщения, у выводится ошибка

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
> Цитата

Надеюсь, я дал достаточно информации, чтобы вы смогли мне помочь, спасибо! :)